# Spring / Hibernate access different database in same mySQL

Tags: database, spring, hibernate

I'm attempting to access two databases simultaneously from the same Java class in Spring/hibernate. They are identical in terms of structure. and they both reside in the same mySql instance. I'll call them "myDatabaseA" and "myDatabaseB".

My plan is to replicate the DAO and Entity classes into different packages, for example "com.entities.packageA" and "com.entities.packageB".  In the entities, I'll use the "catalog" keyword of the table annotation to disambiguate the databases, e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog="myDatabaseB", name = "myTable1")
```

Finally, in the Session Factory bean, I will attempt to specify the entities for both databases in the "basePackages" property as follows:

```
<!--  Session factory bean -->
<b:bean id="sessionFactory" class="com.mycompany.spring.ExtendedAnnotationSessionFactoryBean"">
    <b:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <b:property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
    <b:property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
    <b:property name="entityInterceptor" ref="baseEntityInterceptor" />
    <b:property name="basePackages">
        <b:list>
            <b:value>com.entities.myPackageA</b:value>
            <b:value>com.entities.myPackageB</b:value>
        </b:list>
    </b:property>
</b:bean>
```

In the code, when accessing myDatabaseA, I'll use the entities and daos from "myPackageA", and myPackageB when accessing myDatabaseB.

Does this make sense? I'm kind of new to Spring/Hibernate, so this could be way off base.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are identical you don't have to replicate the classes. Just have two dataSource and two sessionFactories.  While configuring the dataSource the jdbcUrl can specifiy the database name.

If different databases need to be used based on some parameter like user who is accessing it you can look at using a [dynamic routing datasource](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

Comment: It's the same mySql instance, but different databases within that instance. How would I specify which session I'm utilizing in the client code?

Answer (score 0):

Define two different sessionFactories in your application-config file, both pointing to different databases. 
When you are autowiring  these two sessionFactories in your application, use @Qualifier annotation to load both of them.In this way, you will get access to both the databases in your application by using corresponding sessionFactory.